# Temporarily add script on page using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm currently working on a gulp project and I have this `gulpfile.js`

```
var config = require('./config.json'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: './',
        port: config.port,
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src('./' + config.creatives + '/**/*.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['./' + config.creatives + '/**/*.html'], ['html']);
    gulp.watch(['./' + config.creatives + '/**/*.css'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return runSequence('server', ['html', 'watch']);
});
```

the `config.json` content is

```
{
    "port" : "2727",
    "creatives" : "creatives"
}
```

My question is how can I add a temporary script file to the page I'm currently viewing? I saw `connect-livereload` is adding `livereload.js` on the bottom of my page & I would like to do the same. Thanks in advance.

**--- UPDATE--- 14-03-2017 ---**

I update the `gulpfile.js` server with the code below, but the `test.js` is being injected to the file permanently.

```
gulp.task('server', function() {
    connect.server({
        ...
        livereload: true,
        middleware: function(connect, option) {
            return [
                function(req, res, next) {
                    var file, path;
                    if (req.url.indexOf('preview') > -1) {
                        file = req.url;
                        path = file.replace('index.html', '')
                        gulp.src('./' + file)
                            .pipe(insertLines({
                                'before': /<\/body>$/,
                                'lineBefore': '<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>'
                            }))
                            .pipe(gulp.dest('./' + path));
                    }
                    next();
                }
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

I only need to add the `test.js` when the server starts & remove if when server ends.

Comment: Maybe you could check gulp-inject. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

Comment: `gulp-inject` inject scripts permanently to the page, i only need temporary, like only when i run gulp, but when the porject is ready for deployment , that temporary script won't be included.

check `conmect-livereload`, it add `livereload.js` on the page when your viewing the page, but that script will never be included in deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution by editing the module itself using gulp.
Not sure if this is correct, but for me, this is fine (for now).

**Solution**

I made a `update-module.js` file and has this scripts:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    tap = require('gulp-tap'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./node_modules/connect-livereload/index.js')
        .pipe(rename('~index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./node_modules/connect-livereload/'))
        .pipe(tap(function(file, callback) {
            var newFile = file.contents.toString(),
                oldText = 'return \'<script src="\' + src + \'" async="" defer=""></script>\'',
                newtext = 'return \'<script src="\' + src + \'" async="" defer=""></script><script src="http://localhost:3000/temp.js" ></script>\'';
                newContents = newFile.replace(oldText, newtext);
            file.contents = new Buffer(newContents);
            return file;
        }))
        .pipe(rename('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./node_modules/connect-livereload/'));
});
```

I run this script once by typing `gulp --gulpfile ./update-module.js` on my terminal.

What it does is look for `connect-livereload` module and copy the `index.js`, rename it to `~index.js` (for backup), then modify `index.js` to include my temporary script (`temp.js`) and save it on same location as `index.js`.